# How to get type of uploaded file into MediaType

Tags: node.js, http, flutter, dart

I'm using http package on my dart client side for uploading my images to server.

```
 Future<void> createProfile(Profile profile) async {
    try {
      var request =
          new http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(APIPath.createProfile()));
      request.fields.addAll(profile.toMap());
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
          'image', profile.image.path,
          contentType: MediaType('image', 'png'))); //<- specified png image type
      request.headers['authorization'] = "Bearer $_token";
      final response = await request.send();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) print('Uploaded!');

      notifyListeners();
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

and I'm using Multer in my server side node.js to allow certain type of images

```
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
   console.log(file.mimetype); //<-- prints image/png for jpg files
   if (file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/gif' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
      cb(null, true);
   } else {
      const error = new Error('Only images are allowed')
      error.statusCode = 406;
      cb(error);
   }
}
```

I have noticed that when image of type `jpg` is uploaded from my client side to server then in server is recognised as `png` specified in `contentType: MediaType('image', 'png')` but saved as `jpg`. I want to only allowed types specified in my server so how can I get current uploaded image type into my `MediaType` without hardcoding it `MediaType('image', 'png')`?

Comment: what if you remove `contentType: MediaType('image', 'png'))` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe then server or Multer doesn't recognise it as image.. It is a weird. I really don't get the point of it unless I manage to somehow get that type of uploaded image (jpg, png, ect) into that media type

Comment: If you not adding the `contentType`, what is the `file.memetype`?

Comment: @JohnJoe it prints `application/octet-stream`

Comment: maybe you can follow this https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/250, use `mime` package.

Comment: @JohnJoe that issue is for dio package and basically he asking the same question without any answer. I really don't get it...

Comment: @JohnJoe I think I managed to solve it by replacing hardcoded type `png` with `contentType: MediaType('image', profile.image.path.split(".").last)` I really don't know if this is the right way of doing it.. I'm really confused