# How to get type of file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to find a package which would recognise file type. For example

```dart
final path = "/some/path/to/file/file.jpg";
```

should be recognised as image or

```dart
final path = "/some/path/to/file/file.doc";
```

should be recognised as document

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can make use of the [`mime` package from the Dart team](https://pub.dev/packages/mime) to extract the [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) from file names:

```dart
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';

final mimeType = lookupMimeType('/some/path/to/file/file.jpg'); // 'image/jpeg'
```

### Helper functions

If you want to know whether a file *path* represents an **image**, you can create a function like this:

```dart
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';

bool isImage(String path) {
  final mimeType = lookupMimeType(path);

  return mimeType.startsWith('image/');
}
```

Likewise, if you want to know if a *path* represents a **document**, you can write a function like this:

```dart
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';

bool isDocument(String path) {
  final mimeType = lookupMimeType(path);

  return mimeType == 'application/msword';
}
```

---

You can find lists of MIME types [at IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) or look at the [extension map in the `mime` package](https://github.com/dart-lang/mime/blob/c551c43d09e2290e033c90ed8d911140d4bcef20/lib/src/default_extension_map.dart#L8).

### From file headers

With the `mime` package, you can even check against header bytes of a file:

```dart
final mimeType = lookupMimeType('image_without_extension', headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]); // jpeg
```

Comment: oh man thank you very much.. actually that is main reason I asked about it.. I'm using mime in my backend and therefore I need this information in my front end... Thank you very much. Now I feel like an idiot not to at least try to look for that package

Comment: can you please explain how to actually use it in MultiPart http request.. I already asked about it with no answer.. It looks to me that with this package I don't really need to specify type and extension in MediaType.. Just can not figure out how to do it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344958/how-to-get-type-of-uploaded-file-into-mediatype

Comment: whats the 0xFF, 0xD8 for?

Comment: It doesn't support a lot of mime types though, like HEIC or BMP.

Comment: @OliverDixon you can contribute to a package :)

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot  How can I find the mime type of pdf file that doesn't have a .pdf extension on the filename?? headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8] always return mime type as image/jpeg, so how is it possible to identify a document without any extension ??

Comment: @KJEjava48 You will have to pass the actual header bytes of the file. `[0xFF, 0xD8]` is only applicable for the jpeg example.

Comment: pdf file returned image/jpeg :(((

Answer (score 11):

There is no need of any extension. You can try below code snippet.

```
String getFileExtension(String fileName) {
    return ".${fileName.split('.').last}".toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If think you should take a look to [path package](https://pub.dev/packages/path), specially to [extension method](https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/Context/extension.html).
You can get file format without adding one more package to pubspec.yaml ;)

```
context.extension('foo.bar.dart.js', 2);   // -> '.dart.js
context.extension('foo.bar.dart.js', 3);   // -> '.bar.dart.js'
context.extension('foo.bar.dart.js', 10);  // -> '.bar.dart.js'
context.extension('path/to/foo.bar.dart.js', 2);  // -> '.dart.js'
```

Answer (score -2):

If the filename contains extension then use below code :

```
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';

File file = getFile();  // use any filepicker
final mimeType = lookupMimeType(file.path);
```

if the filename doesn't have an extension then use :

```
var dataHeader = await file.readAsBytes();
mimeType = lookupMimeType(file.path, headerBytes: dataHeader);
```

Full code :

```
String? mimeType = lookupMimeType(file!.path);
if(mimeType == null) {
   var dataHeader = await file.readAsBytes();
   mimeType = lookupMimeType(file!.path, headerBytes: dataHeader);
}
```

Comment: It will read the entire file to get the `headerBytes`. Press F for the user's memory if they select a 10GB file.

Comment: @AlexRintt then what will be the best way to find the mimetype of a file( with or without the extension ) with minimum load ?

Comment: Use openRead() from File class. It returns a stream that you can manipulate to load the first kilobyte only.