# Flutter / Dart. How to delete all files but leave 10 latest

Tags: flutter, dart

How to delete all files in the temp device directory but leave 10 latest with mime type 'audio/mpeg'.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your current code so we can go though it.

Comment: Get all files, filter out non-"audio/mpeg" files, and sort the remaining files based on creation time

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the folder, read the mime type and leave at least 10 files there?

The MIME type can be retrieved as shown in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62361799/9080974)

Now all that's left is to iterate through the files, where the MIME-type is the desired one, and delete all but 10.

```
Directory dirToPrune = ...;
List<File> result = [];

for(FileSystemEntity entity in dirToPrune.listSync())
  if(entity is File && lookupMimeType(entity.path)=="audio/mpeg")
    result.add(entity);

while(result.length > 10) {
  File toDelete = result[0];
  result.removeAt(0);
  toDelete.delete();
}
```

I did not test the code but the idea should be clear.